# What exactly do the "==" and "is" operators compare in D?

Tags: d

From "Programming in D" book I learnt that `==` operator needs to access the objects in order to evaluate the expression on the left and on the right before returning the boolean value. Thus it is not suitable for comparing whether the object is `null`.

> ... the == operator may need to consult the values of the members of the objects and that attempting to access the members through a potentially null variable would cause a memory access error.

also

> Value equality: The == operator that appears in many examples throughout
>   the book compares variables by their values. When two variables are said to
>   be equal in that sense, their values are equal.

So, let's try the following:

```
import std.experimental.all;

int[] arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3];
arr == arr.reverse.array; // --> true
```

Well, this is unexpected. In Scala for instance the same expression returns `False`.

It becomes more clear after you check the memory address of both `arr` and `arr.reverse.array` -- it does not change. So, now the result of `==` makes kind of sense although one would expect it to compare values of the arrays not their addresses, right?

Now, let's try `is` operator which is used to compare object references and should be used to check if the object is `null`. It is also used to compare class variables.

```
arr is arr.reverse.array; // --> false
```

I would expect it to return `true` as well since it compares references. What is actually going on here? Why does `is` returns `false` instead and `==` returns `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` DOES compare values. `is` DOES compare references. Your big mistake is using the function `reverse`.

http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.algorithm.mutation.reverse.html

> Reverses r *in-place.*

emphasis mine. That means it modifies the contents of the original.

I suspect you are also checking the memory address wrong. If you are using `&arr`, you are comparing the address of the local variables, not the array contents. That doesn't change because it is the same local variable, you are just binding to a different array. Check `.ptr` instead of `&` and you will see it changes - the `.array` function always allocates a new array for it.

So == passed because the reverse changed the left hand side at the same time! It wasn't because [1,2,3] == [3,2,1], but rather because after calling reverse, the [1,2,3] was itself modified to [3,2,1] which is == [3,2,1]!.

Now, as to what these operators actually do: `==` checks for some abstract quality of equality. This varies by type: it can be overridden by member functions (which is why calling it on `null` classes is problematic) and frequently does a member-by-member comparison (e.g. array elements or struct pieces).

`is`, on the other hand, does something far simpler: it is a bit comparison of the variable directly, which is closer to an abstract idea of identity, but not quite (like `int a = 3; int b = 3; assert(a is b);` passes because both are 3 but is it the same identity? fuzzy cuz of value type.)

`is` will never call a user-defined function, and will never descend into member references, it just compares the bit values.

(interestingly, `float.nan is float.nan` also returns true, whereas == would not, again just because it compares bit values. But not all nans have the same bit value, so it is not a substitute for isNaN in the math module!)

Comment: Yes, I used `int[]* ptr = &arr;`  before `reverse` and then just checked if it changed after `writeln(*ptr)`. But how do I compare if two arrays are equal? `std.algorithm.comparison.cmp`?

Comment: I hit the wrong button while typing and accidentally submitted early, read it now

Comment: but in short, no `cmp` is meant for string sorting. For plain equality of array members, `==` is the right thing to do. like a == b passes if a and b have the same contents.